# Accessing modified airflow variable as a custom parameter for S3 sensor in AIRFLOW

Tags: python, airflow

let's see if I can explain myself on this matter.

See, I have S3 files that I receive from a customer that are badly formatted. The dates appear with low dashes like "2017_07_10", for example.

Since I want to access them to be able to download them, first I have one task that is an S3 sensor in airflow. It looks like so:

```
xxx = S3KeySensor(
    task_id='task_name',
    bucket_key=BUCKET_KEY,
    wildcard_match=True,
    params={'yesterday_ds_formatted': ????},
    provide_context=True,
    bucket_name=BUCKET_NAME,
    s3_conn_id=S3_CONN_ID,
    timeout=18 * 60 * 60,
    poke_interval=120,
    dag=dag)
```

In the Variables section in Airflow console I have the bucket_key with the template variable {{yesterday_ds_formatted}}.

e.g. : 'folder1/folder2/folder3/blablablablabla-{{params.yesterday_ds_formatted}}*.csv

I need to modify that template variable or something so that it grabs {{yesterday_ds}} and replaces "-" with "_".

How can I do that guys? I can't manage to make it work...
I have tried calling a custom python function when setting the parameter but then I cant access "ds", not even with kwargs. It seems like I cant access template variables before-hand so to speak.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this right, you want to use jinja templates for the `bucket_key` parameter, but that's not supported in S3KeySensor.

An easy way to do that would be to subclass a custom sensor from the `S3KeySensor` like so:

```
TemplatedS3KeySensor(S3KeySensor):
  template_fields = ('bucket_key',)
```